# CSS Selector * does not work for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I want to change some rules of Twitter Bootstrap .span class but it does not work.

I want to change the direction of them and also apply them a border. Here is what I have out:

```
.span*
{
    direction: rtl !important;
    border: 1px #CCC solid !important;
}
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: The `*` selector is only valid on its own, not as part of another simple selector. But if you want to style `.span` elements, what's wrong with simply selecting `.span`?

Comment: put whitespace between span or *

Answer (score 1):

put a space between the * and the selector

```
.span * {
}
```

Comment: thanks, after the proper limit passed I would accept yours as the answer